"First et al.", many authors with same surname, and IEEE citations
I'm describing an evolution of ideas like this:

Wang et al. suggested quantizing the ReLU function [1]. Later, Wang
et al. extended that method by shifting the function base [2]. In
contrast, Wang et al. instead used neurons with multiple spiking thresholds
[3].

I know IEEE allows citations as nouns, but I strongly dislike them
because they ruin the flow of the text. What's the proper style here
if we have multiple Wang et al. published in the same year?

How about: Wang, Smith et al. say underwater basketweaving disturbs local fish populations, while Wang, Miller et al. state that it doesn't.

Does "Wang, Miller et al." work if the three authors are "Wang, Miller, and Jones"?

Since they are all different Wangs (see comment to answer below) I think you need to either (1) add initials to each, if they are different, or (2) rephrase to not use the first author last name to refer to the paper. I suspect the editor will understand why the wording seems more convoluted in that case.

If I was insisting on this format, I might lean on "Wang et al. at XX University ... In contrast, Wang et al. at YY State ...," however I'd probably toss it all together.

This is one of the reasons we generally don't cite by name in my field. It's faster to just say "Quantizing the ReLU function was first suggested in Ref. [1]. Later..."

@knzhou If I see the name and the year, I often recognise the paper without looking it up in the reference section.

This question is similar to: Citing two authors with the same surname – is it worth noting that they are distinct people?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JFabianMeier Me too, but this often doesn't hold true for Chinese names. Chinese surnames are notorious for being non-distinct, there are so many researchers named Wang or Li that the surname aren't really recognizable.

I think this is sufficiently different to https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/91243/citing-two-authors-with-the-same-surname-is-it-worth-noting-that-they-are-dist that I don't want to close it as a dupe, because that question was asking how to handle it in an author-date referencing style and this is with numerical referencing. The best solutions might well be different.
Voting to leave open for now.
But I encourage @GaslightDeceiveSubvert to edit the question to make this clear.

Why not do

F. Wang et al. suggested quantizing the ReLU function [1]. Later, L. Wang, et al. extended that method by shifting the function base [2]. In contrast, C. Wang et al. instead used neurons with multiple spiking thresholds [3].

like described in this answer to a question that this one possibly duplicates.
If two Wangs have the same initial then you could spell out the first names in full. If two Wangs have the same first name then I would just not use names in the text.

In [1], the authors suggested quantizing the ReLU function. Later, the authors in [2] extended that method by shifting the function base. In contrast, the authors in [3] instead used neurons with multiple spiking thresholds.

I would also consider

[1] suggested quantizing the ReLU function. Later, [2] extended that method by shifting the function base. In contrast, [3] instead used neurons with multiple spiking thresholds.

I like this one, but, sadly (to me), I'm pretty sure it's technically incorrect to use citation numbers as pronouns.

I didn't know initials were proper style. Wrt citation numbers, they make it hard to retain the active voice so you have to resort to passive voice, which I hate.

@GaslightDeceiveSubvert two points. (1) I do not know or guarantee that anything I've written above is "proper style". That's between you and the editor of your journal to discuss. But I've seen all of the styles above "in the wild". (2) In both of my examples using citation numbers I used active voice, but yeah it is a little more awkward and difficult. "In [1] the authors suggested" vs "in [1] it was suggested". I don't hate passive voice, I just opt for active when I can and when it's natural.

Using leading initials seems odd; firstly, Wang might be from somewhere (and published somewhere) where given names come last rather than first; secondly, we already index our catalogs with "Surname, Givenname" or "Surname, Initials"

@MartinKealey Indices and bibliographies are alphabetised by surname because we generally only use the surname in references in the text, and alphabetising by given name would make sources impossible to locate. That doesn’t mean that we suspend the normal order of names when mentioning them in the text. Whether it’s “L. Wang et al. wrote…” or “according to renowned physicist L. Wang”, the normal order of names should be used. Whether or not you choose to follow the order in the author’s native (or published?) language is a different matter, where either choice is defensible.

@JanusBahsJacquet by "indeces" I was referring to entire catalogues, and entire shelving sections in libraries, which have traditionally been sorted by surname. It makes sense for references to follow that precedent, if for no other reason than to make the referent easier to find. On the other hand, if I'm talking about a person rather than a publication, it would 100% be appropriate to say "renowned physicist Lillian Wang" in the order that she would normally write it.

How about something like this:
Wang et al. originally suggested quantizing the ReLU function [1]. In subsequent reports, others extended that method by shifting the function base [2], or in contrast by using neurons with multiple spiking thresholds [3].
You don't need to always list authors. The above is a very rough workaround, but you get the idea.

This is OK. However, the 2nd and 3rd Wangs might be much more famous than the 1st, and then this sounds like one of them made the original suggestion. Perhaps you could put the full name of the 1st Wang.

@toby544 Fame seems irrelevant. The "Later" in the original post seems to clearly indicate that that [1] was published before [2]. The time-order of [3] is less clear.

@MichaelMior I meant that if there are three Wangs working in the same field, then it would be better to make it clear which one you are talking about.

@toby544 I think that's already made clear with the citations.

@MichaelMior What do you mean? It will be clear if you look at the references list, certainly. But if you are mentioning one Wang in the main text, like in the example in this answer, then it would be better to make it clear here which one it is.

@toby544 You are making it clear which one it is, it is the one associated with the cited manuscript. The concept of "fame" is silly. You are citing a specific work, you don't need biographical details of the authors. Frankly you don't even need to name any of the authors, it is just a mechanism to break the monotony of writing historical precedent before discussing your science contextually. If you want to cite a body of work with some historical retrospective then you can make a broader reference to a specific author with full detail.

@toby544 I think if it is a surname that is common enough that three separate papers on the topic authored by entirely separate people sharing a surname, the authors can leave it up to the reader to not make assumptions that the author is one specific person, even if they are better known than the others.

@R1NaNo If you just say Wang, then it it not clear at all which one it is, unless you look at the references list (which is extra effort for the reader). We don't need biographical details, but it is helpful to the reader to know which person is being mentioned.

@BryanKrause I don't think any surname is so common that the author can make that assumption about the readers. I still think it is helpful to the readers to say which Wang it is. But you might be right.

@toby544 I think we will just have to agree to disagree because I see no reason why the reader immediately has to know the name of the researcher because we are not appealing to personal authority or opinion, but rather referencing a specific work. Often times the name used is the first author, which is either a graduate student or postdoc and statistically is unlikely to even have a long-term career in academia.

Why not just use "First Author Last Name, 2nd author Last Name, et al." as the in text reference for these particular refs, if you think it improves readability and minimizes confusion?

Aiui, this is incorrect if there are exactly 3 authors.

@GaslightDeceiveSubvert  why?  Is it because et al. is plural, and shouldn't apply to a single author?  I'd respond to either add the third author to the citation or not, as one sees fit or if their mood changes or if it's Thursday.  If a copy editor sees fit to add the third author to the in-text citation, they will.  As publication "errors" go, this is a tiny one, because clarity wins.

It looks like the problem is not that they are all in the same year, but that the abbreviated lists of authors are all the same.
If all three papers have the same list of authors, you can say "they" after the first time.
If it is different lists of authors, you need to rephrase slightly. Perhaps you could say "With other authors, Wang suggested ... Later, he/she ... In contrast, in a third paper he/she ...." Or you could use the passive ("Later, this was extended ..."), if you don't need to say in the text exactly who did each thing.

I am not sure if this is indeed supposed to be the same Wang everytime.

Every Wang in the example is a different person.

OK. Either put the full names or initials and surnames of these three people, or reword it to avoid mentioning their names. (If you give their surnames, you need to make it clear that they are different people.)
