# different online Harvard citation styles

Tags: citation-style

I read some Academia questions, such as [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84686/why-do-so-many-publication-venues-have-their-own-citation-styles), but I'm still wondering about the preference of the following similar, but slightly different formats:

**Option 1**

> Cillizza, C. (2020). *The absolutely remarkable social media power of Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez*. CNN [Online]. 24 July 2020. Available at: <https://edition.cnn.com/2020/07/24/politics/aoc-ted-yoho-cspan/index.html> (Accessed: 23 October 2020).

**Option 2**

> Cillizza, C. (2020). *The absolutely remarkable social media power of Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez*. CNN. 24 July 2020. Available at: https://edition.cnn.com/2020/07/24/politics/aoc-ted-yoho-cspan/index.html (Accessed: 23 October 2020).

The differences here are the `[Online]` and the chevrons (`<>`) around the URL. I understand it doesn't make much of a difference, but I'm interested in what people's preferences are. To me, `option 1` looks more academic, yet `option 2` much cleaner.

Also, please feel free to educate me on anything else here.

Comment: Generally academics (in my experience) don't choose a preferred citation style - journals pick a preferred style and academics conform to it (often by using a citation manager, or through built-in features of software like LaTeX). If you're submitting to a journal (or writing for another purpose, such as an assignment for a class) you should just follow the target's guidelines to have a quiet life!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely agree with the comments. It would be useful to see what the journal wants. You could also check recent works published in the journal you are interested in to verify the appropriate Harvard citation format for publication.

Having said that, personally, I like option 2 for its brevity:

> Cillizza, C. (2020). The absolutely remarkable social media power of Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez. CNN. 24 July 2020. Available at: https://edition.cnn.com/2020/07/24/politics/aoc-ted-yoho-cspan/index.html (Accessed: 23 October 2020).